# ruby ending methods other than end

Tags: ruby

```
awords = []
word = "x"

puts "Type as many words as you want, or press \"enter\" to quit."
while word != ""enter code here
  #get word from user
  word = gets.chomp
  if word == ('')
    puts 'you input nothing'
  end

  #add to array
  awords.push word 
end



#user exited loop test for array before printing

puts "Now sorting what you typed.. thanks."
puts awords.sort
```

Everything works fine, but I want this program to skip last two "puts" if users don't input anything. Is there anyway I could just stop program after `puts 'you input nothing'` if users decide not to input but press enter?

Comment: Hey Hong Kim, did I answer your question? If so, can you mark it as the accepted answer- if not, what can I clarify for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to puts the last two lines, then you should check to make sure there are values within `awords`.

```
awords = []
word = 'x'

puts "Type as many words as you want, or press \"enter\" to quit."
until word.empty?
  word = gets.chomp
  if word.empty?
    puts 'you input nothing'
  end

  awords << word
end


# Check to make sure awords has values in it
unless awords.empty?
  puts "Now sorting what you typed.. thanks."
  puts awords.sort
end
```

Now the easiest way to stop the program early if no input was ever given is to add a line after `puts 'you input nothing'` with a `return`.

```
puts 'you input nothing'
return if awords.empty?
```

You'll notice that I changed a lot of your `== ''` methods to `.empty?` because that is the ruby way of doing that type of check with strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
awords = []
word = 'x'

puts "Type as many words as you want, or press \"enter\" to quit."
until word.empty?
  word = gets.chomp
  if word.empty?
    puts 'you input nothing'
  end

  awords << word
end


# Check to make sure awords has values in it
unless awords.empty?
  puts "Now sorting what you typed.. thanks."
  puts awords.sort
end
```

thank you that was very clear

Comment: Hey Hong Kim, it looks like my answer was helpful. The way to use this site is by clicking the checkmark under the upvote/downvote arrows on my answer to show that it was the correct answer to your question. A couple people downvoted this answer because you didn't do that.